# Is AWS s3 "Put Object - copy" performed async?

Tags: amazon-s3

Suppose I have a huge file in Amazon S3 (1 GiB, for example). If I call the `put object - copy` operation to create a copy in another bucket, will Amazon S3 respond the HTTP request only after the actual copy is finished (holding my TCP connection), or will it just respond with a "OK, your object will be copied" (releasing my TCP connection)?

I couldn't find the answer in the [operation description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html).

The [proposal document](https://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/copy.html) of the operation seems to mention something about my question, but it's not clear enough (actually a bit confusing):

> Since we want to mitigate the possibility for time outs during long copy operations, the response to a copy is slightly different than other operations in Amazon S3—once Amazon S3 initiates the actual copy, it will respond with a 200 response. To determine whether the copy was successful, check the returned body for a CopyObjectResult body, which will contain the LastModified date and ETag of the uploaded object. If the copy fails, Amazon S3 might respond with a non-200 error as it does today.
>
> The returned data is an XML document. After the XML declaration, there are a number of whitespace characters that you must read, after which there will be either a CopyObjectResult element or a standard error document. The number of whitespace characters sent to you will be determined by the time required for Amazon S3 to perform the copy operation.

Comment: Possibly related: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-transfer-manager-to-copy-amazon-s3-objects/

Answer (score 0):

I found it in another AWS Doc, it may clear your confusion:

> A copy request might return an error when Amazon S3 receives the copy
>   request or while Amazon S3 is copying the files. If the error occurs
>   before the copy operation starts, you receive a standard Amazon S3
>   error. If the error occurs during the copy operation, the error
>   response is embedded in the 200 OK response. This means that a 200 OK
>   response can contain either a success or an error. Design your
>   application to parse the contents of the response and handle it
>   appropriately.
>   If the copy is successful, you receive a response with information about the copied object.

[AWS Put Object - Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html)

Although, it doesn't say anything about copy being a async. In general, put object for large files is usually multipart requests.

Comment: Multipart is for files larger than 5GiB, I don't need that now.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP SDK (not sure others, but it may be similar) there have different methods to copy.

Document is in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject).

### 1. CopyObject

This works sync, which means it will wait until finish the job.

`$client->copyObject($args)`

`$args` is key-value array, detail is in the document.

### 2. CopyObjectAsync

This works async, which means server will **not** wait the job.

`$client->copyObjectAsync($args)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CopyObjectAsync` method in various APIs (Jave, .net, ruby, etc.), and a CopyObjectRequest class, and, as usual, AWS' documentation is really terrible to search.